# Solr query text_general

Tags: solr, solrj

I have a text_general with value ABC100001.00. When I search for ABC or ABC100001 or ABC100001.00 or abc or abc100001 or abc100001.00 or 100001 or 100001.00 I want the record to be retrieve. How can I do this? Currently it will return records that are with .00 which I do not want.

Below is my schema.xml

```
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
     <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
     <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
     <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" tokenSeparator=""/> 
     <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
     <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>      
     -->
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>      
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Is the last part always `00`? Or is it always two digits between `00` and `99`?

Comment: @MatsLindh always 2 digits ranging from 00 to 99

Comment: @MatsLindh Just to also add, the value could be this as well. ABC100001/003. The last part ranging from 001 to 999

Comment: So how about `ABC10` - would you want that to match? (i.e. a prefix search) - is there any case where just searching for numbers should give a match for this field?

Comment: @MatsLindh ABC10 shouldn't return. For ABC100001.00, when I search for ABC or ABC100001 or ABC100001.00 or abc or abc100001 or abc100001.00 or 100001 or 100001.00, I expect record to be retrieved.

Comment: @MatsLindh For ABC100001/003, when I search for ABC or ABC100001 or ABC100001/003 or abc or abc100001 or abc100001/003 or 100001 or 100001/003 or /003 or 003, I expect record to be retrieved.